# React router v4 get user confirmation when leaving page

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

In older versions I could use setRouteLeaveHook within my component.

For example (SO): [Detecting user leaving page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page)

With react router v4 the logic has changed away from injecting the router itself into the components and I only found the following function on router v4:

[BrowserRouter. getUserConfirmation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/getUserConfirmation-func)

I am a little bit confused, why I should link the confirm behavior with the Router itself and not with a specific component!?

How can I place a confirm window, when leaving my component (linked to my current route), while being in a certain state? This seems to be not supported by the function above.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the [Prompt component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Prompt) is what you're looking for. Just render it in the component you want to confirm navigation form, i.e. the same component you render in your `<Route>`.

Comment: Looks promising and I wonder why I did not found it on react training before. Will check that out and respond on success/fail.

Comment: I've been looking for a way to have a custom prompt for the user, may be something like [ample-alerts](https://github.com/myTerminal/ample-alerts). However, most implementations use this specific method and it relies on the browser default prompt.

Answer (score 3):

[react-router-navigation-prompt](https://github.com/zacharyrsmith/react-router-navigation-prompt) also does what you want: it is a more powerful `<Prompt />`.

Comment: This worked for me, It prompts default system prompt, No need to use other modals.