# React Show a custom modal on browser back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a route named PROFILE where a user is presented with a form.

what I want to do is show a custom modal when user click on the browser back button if the form is dirty, otherwise the browser back button should have the default behaviour.

Is that possible?

`react-router-dom` - `4.2.2`
`react` - `16.0.0`

Any help is Appreciated

Comment: Check out my answer to this question. https://stackoverflow.com/a/66873913/5782438

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router';

componentDidMount() {
    this.backListener = browserHistory.listen(location => {
      if (location.action === "POP") {
        // Show your model
      }
    });
  }

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.backListener();
}
```

for more information : [Intercept/handle browser's back button in React-router?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39342195/intercept-handle-browsers-back-button-in-react-router)