# How to prevent users from accidental route change in react router v3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to implement a hook that prevents users from 'unintended' route change such as back button or reload. I am using react-router v3, so `<Prompt />` in react router v4 does not work for me.

I have looked into `setRouteLeaveHook` but it does not handle accidental reload action. Any suggestion would be appreciated :)

Comment: have a look on this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue, and I I had my own solution manipulating both `setRouteLeaveHook` and `onbeforeunload`.

Here is a link to my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page/50388073#50388073)