# How to prevent user from leaving current route? React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-v4

I have one sensitive route `/test`. And if the user wants to leave this route, I want to show him some confirmation window, if he presses **cancel** button - nothing is going to change if he confirms then - `function some()` must be executed and route must also be changed.

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/preventing-transitions

Comment: Please check this question [Detect User leaving Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page-with-react-router/45869459#45869459)

Comment: @Se0ng11, thank you very much. It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri Thank you very much, you just save my day.

Comment: @NazariyMural glad to have helped