# Setting React hooks state before function call

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-hooks

Im having trouble setting `page = 1`  before calling the `handleSearchClick` function in `resetStates`. Currently when `resetStates` is being called (which is after a `search button` is clicked) it does not reset page to 1 on the first click but on the second search click it does.

I tried using a `async await` but thats not reseting page to 1 before handleSearchClick. How do I reset page to 1 before the function call? Any feedback is appreciated.

This is what Im currently doing:

```
const resetStates = async () => {
            const promise1 = setHasMore(true);
            const promise2 = await setPage(1);
            Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
                .then(() => {
                 /* At this point I want page to equal 1 */
                    handleSearchClick(); 
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    throw new Error(error);
                });
        };

    /**
     * Handles event on search click
     */
    const handleSearchClick = async () => {
        setItems([]);
        setIsLoading(true);
        const base = handleBaseId();
        const items = await fetchSearchPayload(page, value, option, base);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setInitialLoad(true);
        setItems(items);
        console.log('On Click', { option }, { page });
    };

 <SearchBar
    onClickButton={resetStates}
    onValueChange={handleChange}
    value={value}
    pageNum={page}
    onEnter={handleSearchOnEnter}
  />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`state updater is asynchronous`, but it doesn't return you a promise, so you cant use `await` to wait for the promise to complete.  Instead you can pass on the page value as an argument

```
    const resetStates = async () => {
            setHasMore(true);
            setPage(1);
            handleSearchClick(1); 
    };

    /**
     * Handles event on search click
     */
    const handleSearchClick = async (page) => {
        setItems([]);
        setIsLoading(true);
        const base = handleBaseId();
        const items = await fetchSearchPayload(page, value, option, base);
        setIsLoading(false);
        setInitialLoad(true);
        setItems(items);
        console.log('On Click', { option }, { page });
    };

 <SearchBar
    onClickButton={resetStates}
    onValueChange={handleChange}
    value={value}
    pageNum={page}
    onEnter={handleSearchOnEnter}
  />
```

or else you can make use of useEffect to wait for state update

```
const prevPage = usePrevious(page);
const prevHasMore = usePrevious(hasMore);
const initialRender = useRef(true);
useEffect(() => {
   if(initialRender.current !== true) {
        // you can check for hasMore also here
        if((prevPage !== page && page == 1) && (prevHasMore !== hasMore && hasMore === true)) {
            handleSearchClick();
        }
   }
}, [hasMore, page])

const resetStates = async () => {
        setHasMore(true);
        setPage(1);

};

/**
 * Handles event on search click
 */
const handleSearchClick = async (page) => {
    setItems([]);
    setIsLoading(true);
    const base = handleBaseId();
    const items = await fetchSearchPayload(page, value, option, base);
    setIsLoading(false);
    setInitialLoad(true);
    setItems(items);
    console.log('On Click', { option }, { page });
};
```

You can refer the implementation of `usePrevious` from the below post

[How to compare oldValues and newValues on React Hooks useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446020/how-to-compare-oldvalues-and-newvalues-on-react-hooks-useeffect/53446665#53446665)

Comment: page is a state. I have it initialized as  `const [page, setPage] = React.useState(1);` if I pass 1 as an argument it wont be updated to state. is there a way I can reset it to 1 and not pass a hardcoded number ?

Comment: Updating my answer for that

Comment: Glad to have helped