# Run Effect hook only when both dependencies change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React component that fetches data using the `useEffect` hook like so:

```
const cache = {key: "data-fetched-using-key"}
function Config({key, options}) {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchedData; // fetch data using key and options
        setData(fetchedData);
        cache[key] = fetchedData;
    }, [key, options])
    return <p>{data}</p>;
}
```

This runs the hook every time `key` or `options` change. However, I'm also caching the data locally, and only want the effect to run when both `key` AND `options` change (since for each key/options combination the data will always be the same).

Is there a clean way to depend on the combination of `key` AND `options` rather than `key` OR `options` using React Hooks?

Comment: Yes, there is. You would need to use useCallback hook.

Answer (score 11):

You can create this sort of logic with `useRef()`. Consider the following example and sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-useeffect-with-multiple-reqs-6ece5

```
const App = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState();
  const [age, setAge] = useState();

  const previousValues = useRef({ name, age });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (
      previousValues.current.name !== name &&
      previousValues.current.age !== age
    ) {
      //your logic here
      console.log(name + " " + age);
      console.log(previousValues.current);

      //then update the previousValues to be the current values
      previousValues.current = { name, age };
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        placeholder="name"
        value={name}
        onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
      />
      <input
        placeholder="age"
        value={age}
        onChange={e => setAge(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Workflow:**

1. We create a `ref` object for the two values we want to keep track of,
   in this case its a `name` and `age`. The ref object is `previousValues`.
2. `useEffect` is defined but we do not provide it any dependencies.
   Instead, we just have it execute whenever there is a state-change to
   `name` or `age`.
3. Now inside `useEffect` we have conditional logic to check whether the
   previous/initial values of both `name` and `age` are different than
   their corresponding state-values. If they are then good we execute
   our logic `(console.log)`.
4. Lastly after executing the logic, update the ref object `(previousValues)` to the current values `(state)`.

Answer (score 7):

In order to run the effect when both values change, you need to make use of the previous values and compare them within the hook when either key or options change.

You can write a `usePrevious` hook and compare old and previous state as mentioned in this post:

[How to compare oldValues and newValues on React Hooks useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446020/how-to-compare-oldvalues-and-newvalues-on-react-hooks-useeffect/53446665#53446665)

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  return ref.current;
}

const cache = {key: "data-fetched-using-key"}
function Config({key, options}) {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const previous = usePrevious({key, options});
    useEffect(() => {
        if(previous.key !== key && previous.options !== options) {
            const fetchedData; // fetch data using key and options
            setData(fetchedData);
            cache[key] = fetchedData;
        }
    }, [key, options])
    return <p>{data}</p>;
}
```

Comment: Nice, I like this alot too. :)

Comment: This is great, thank you! Definitely gonna remember usePrevious :)

Answer (score 3):

All provided solutions are perfectly fine, However there are some more complex situation e.g., When useEffect function should be called ONLY when dependency A and B changed while it also depends on C's value.

So I suggest using sequence of useEffects and intermediate States to provide more space for future logics. Implementation of this approach for asked question would be:

```
const cache = {key: "data-fetched-using-key"}
function Config({key, options}) {
    const [data, setData] = useState();

    const [needsUpdate, setNeedsUpdate] = useState(()=>({key:false, option:false}));

    useEffect(()=>{
      setNeedsUpdate((needsUpdate)=>({...needsUpdate, key:true}));
    },[key])

    useEffect(()=>{
      setNeedsUpdate((needsUpdate)=>({...needsUpdate, options:true}));
    },[options])

    useEffect(() => {
      if (needsUpdate.key && needsUpdate.options){
        const fetchedData; // fetch data using key and options
        setData(fetchedData);
        cache[key] = fetchedData;
        setNeedsUpdate(()=>({key:false, option:false}));
      }
    }, [needsUpdate, key, options])
    return <p>{data}</p>;
}
```

In this way we can apply almost any logic on our useEffect dependencies, However it has own drawbacks which is few more rendering cycle.

Comment: what if there are 4 dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new custom hook which calls the callback with an argument with index/names of dependencies

```
const useChangesEffect = (callback, dependencies, dependencyNames = null) => {
  const prevValues = useRef(dependencies);

  useEffect(() => {
    const changes = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < prevValues.current.length; i++) {
      if (!shallowEqual(prevValues.current[i], dependencies[i])) {
        changes.push(dependencyNames ? dependencyNames[i] : i);
      }
    }
    callback(changes);
    prevValues.current = dependencies;
  }, dependencies);
};


useChangesEffect((changes) => {
  if (changes.includes(0)) {
    console.log('dep1 changed');
  }
  if (changes.includes(1)) {
    console.log('dep2 changed');
  }
}, [dep1, dep2]);
```