# How to await a setState call finishing when using useState hook that immediately needs that state to make an API call?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a voice dictation custom hook, along with a separate custom hook that appends the dictation results to an object that stores "Note" values.

If the user clicks save too early, there are still Partial Results that I need to append right before an API call that saves the Note.

My code looks like this

```
function NoteDictation(props) {

  const [
    results,
    partialResults,
    error,
    toggleRecognizing,
    speechHasStarted,
  ] = useDictation();

    const [note, setNote, saveNoteAPICall, updateNoteAPICall] = useNote({})
    //Use Note is a custom hook that has that certain type of note's properties built in (they're medical notes, and we have a custom hook for each type of note).



    function handleSavePress(){

      if(partialSpeechResults){
        //If the dictation software hasn't returned a final result, 
        //append the partialSpeechResults
        setNote({...note, text: note.text +  partialSpeechResults})
      }


      //SaveNote does not use the value set above if there are partial results.
      saveNote()
    }

    return (
     <View>
       <NoteContents note={note} results={results} partialResults={partialResults} />
       <Button onPress={handleSavePress> />
    </View>
    )

}
```

Problem is, the SaveNote is being called and is using the old state of the  note...the setting of the state is not completing on time.

I can't seem to use a useEffect hook here to monitor the change, since I am calling the API to save the note right away and it's accessing the note state when saving.

What is the best way to handle this? Thank you.

Comment: Currently, setState in useState hook doesn't support callback. But you can use a useEffect hook to do 'after render' callbacks and coordinate with the current state value.

Comment: Yep understood, but as mentioned above I have a unique case where I am using the value immediately afterwards to save it in an API call.

Comment: Maybe this answer can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446020/how-to-compare-oldvalues-and-newvalues-on-react-hooks-useeffect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### EDIT

Given the updated code, you should be able to handle it very similarly to how I outlined in my original answer:

```
// will run on mount and whenever note changes
useEffect(() => {
  // skip first run (what you check depends on your initial note value)
  if (Object.keys(note).length) {
    saveNoteAPICall()
  }
}, [note])

function handleSavePress(){
  if(partialSpeechResults){
    // If the dictation software hasn't returned a final result, 
    // append the partialSpeechResults
    // and let if fall into useEffect when note updates
    setNote({...note, text: note.text +  partialSpeechResults})
  } else {
    // run immediately if not partial
    saveNoteAPICall()
  }
}
```

The key difference is that you only call `saveNote` inside your press handler if you don't have a partial result. That way you don't get incomplete saves. If you `setNote`, it will drop into your `useEffect` and save with the right value.

If this is a common pattern for handling these notes, it might make sense to move this logic into your `useNote` hook.

---

#### Original answer

Since you're using `useState` for your `note` value, you should be able to handle this with `useEffect`. Values from `useState` are immutable, so they work great as inputs for effects hooks. Move your call to `saveNote()` outside of `handleSavePress` and into `useEffect`:

```
const [note, setNote] = useState({})

// ...Other misc code

// this will run on first execution,
// and then any time the value of note changes
useEffect(() => {
  // skip first run
  if (Object.keys(note).length) {
    saveNote(note)
  }
}, [note])

function handleSavePress(){
  if (partialSpeechResults) {
    // If the dictation software hasn't returned a final result, 
    // append the partialSpeechResults
    setNote({ ...note, text: note.text +  partialSpeechResults })
  }
}
```

If, for some reason, your `saveNote` function is defined inside this component, I would suggest moving it outside the component and passing it `note` as an argument so you can be sure `useEffect` will run only when you want it to. If there is some compelling reason why you need to define `saveNote` inside the component, then you should define `saveNote` with `useCallback` and change your `useEffect` function to key off changes to that:

```
const [note, setNote] = useState({})

// ...Other misc code

// this function will only change when note changes
const saveNote = useCallback(() => {
  // whatever api call you need to run here
  // that uses the note value in scope
}, [note])

// this will run on first execution,
// and then any time the value of note (and thus saveNote) changes
useEffect(() => {
  // skip first run
  if (Object.keys(note).length) {
    saveNote()
  }
}, [saveNote, note])

function handleSavePress(){
  if (partialSpeechResults) {
    // If the dictation software hasn't returned a final result, 
    // append the partialSpeechResults
    setNote({ ...note, text: note.text +  partialSpeechResults })
  }
}
```

It's difficult to determine exactly where things might be going wrong without seeing a more complete code example. The `// ...Other misc code` section of your example is kind of important, particularly where and how you're defining `saveNote`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed comment. Just updated my code with some more details. Basically, I have the results of the useDictation hook fed into my component, and if there are partial results still returned before the array, I'd like to add it to the note. I have multiple hooks with the saveAPICalls baked inside of them, so if I have to update the functions to take in the note vs accessing it inside the hook, I have to update a lot of hooks (we have a lot of note types).

Comment: That would qualify as a compelling reason to define it inline :)

Comment: hehe :) Unfortunately I can't make an API call for every state update on the note, it would kill my AWS bills :)

Answer (score 1):

Try the useEffect hook:

**EDIT:** Since it runs on first render you want to be sure the note object is not empty before saving

```
useEffect(() => {

    if(Object.keys(note).length !== 0){

        saveNote();
    }

});
```

Comment: This doesn't work if I understand correctly, since that way it will either fire on every change of the dependency, or on mount.

Comment: Correct—this will run on every render, which would not be great for your api. You need a dependency array to keep it from getting out of hand.

Comment: You can check if the note object is empty before calling the saveNote function. @stephenlizcano