# More advanced comparison in React's useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am looking for a way to perform more advanced comparison instead of the second parameter of the `useEffect` React hook.

Specifically, I am looking for something more like this:

```
useEffect(
  () => doSomething(), 
  [myInstance],
  (prev, curr) => { /* compare prev[0].value with curr[0].value */ }
);
```

Is there anything I missed from the React docs about this or is there any way of implementing such a hook on top of what already exists, please?

If there is a way to implement this, this is how it would work: the second parameter is an array of dependencies, just like the `useEffect` hook coming from React, and the third is a callback with two parameters: the array of dependencies *at the previous render*, and the array of dependencies *at the current render*.

Comment: you could use React.memo function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `class based components` was easy to perform a `deep comparison`. `componentDidUpdate` provides a `snapshot` of `previous props` and `previous state`

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapshot){
    if(prevProps.foo !== props.foo){ /* ... */ }
}
```

The problem is `useEffect` it's not exactly like `componentDidUpdate`. Consider the following

```
useEffect(() =>{
    /* action() */
},[props])
```

The only thing you can assert about the current `props` when `action()` gets called is that it changed (shallow comparison asserts to `false`). You cannot have a snapshot of `prevProps` cause `hooks` are like regular functions, there aren't part of a lifecycle (and don't have an instance) which ensures synchronicity (and inject arguments). Actually the only thing ensuring hooks value integrity is the [order of execution](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html).

**Alternatives to `usePrevious`**

Before updating check if the values are equal

```
   const Component = props =>{
       const [foo, setFoo] = useState('bar')

       const updateFoo = val => foo === val ? null : setFoo(val)
   }
```

This can be useful in some situations when you need to ensure an `effect` to run only once(not useful in your use case).

`useMemo`:
If you want to perform comparison to prevent unecessary `render` calls (`shoudComponentUpdate`), then  `useMemo` is the way to go

```
export React.useMemo(Component, (prev, next) => true)
```

But when you need to get access to the `previous` value inside an already running effect there is no alternatives left. Cause if you already are inside `useEffect` it means that the `dependency` it's already updated (current render).

**Why `usePrevious` works**
`useRef` isn't just for `refs`, it's a very straightforward way to `mutate` values without triggering a re render. So the cycle is the following

- `Component` gets mounted
- `usePrevious` stores the inital value inside `current`
- `props` changes triggering a re render inside `Component`
- `useEffect` is called
- `usePrevious` is called

Notice that the `usePrevious` is always called after the `useEffect` (remember, order matters!). So everytime you are inside an `useEffect` the `current` value of `useRef` will always be one render behind.

```
const usePrevious = value =>{
    const ref = useRef()
    useEffect(() => ref.current = value,[value])
}

const Component = props =>{
    const { A } = props
    useEffect(() =>{
        console.log('runs first')
    },[A])

    //updates after the effect to store the current value (which will be the previous on next render
    const previous = usePrevious(props)
}
```

Answer (score 4):

you could use React.memo function:

```
const areEqual = (prevProps, nextProps) => {
  return (prevProps.title === nextProps.title)
};

export default React.memo(Component, areEqual);
```

or use custom hooks for that:

[How to compare oldValues and newValues on React Hooks useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446020/how-to-compare-oldvalues-and-newvalues-on-react-hooks-useeffect)

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem recently and a solution that worked for me is to create a custom `useStateWithCustomComparator` hook.

In your the case of your example that would mean to replace

`const [myInstance, setMyInstance] = useState(..)`

with

`const [myInstance, setMyInstance] = useStateWithCustomComparator(..)`

The code for my custom hook in Typescript looks like that:

```
const useStateWithCustomComparator = <T>(initialState: T, customEqualsComparator: (obj1: T, obj2: T) => boolean) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);

    const changeStateIfNotEqual = (newState: any) => {
        if (!customEqualsComparator(state, newState)) {
            setState(newState);
        }
    };

    return [state, changeStateIfNotEqual] as const;
};
```