# React useEffect and async fetch

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Here is my code:

```
const useMyFetch = (url, options) => 
{
  const [response, setResponse]   = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => 
  {
    console.log("going to fetch ", url);

    fetch(url, options).then(async function(response) 
    {
      var json = await response.json();
      setResponse(json.message);
    });

  }, [ url ]); 

  return response;
};



function Example() 
{
  const res = useMyFetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random", { method: 'GET' });

  if (!res) 
  {
    return <div>loading...</div>
  }

  return <img src={res} alt="an image" />;
}
```

It looks that everything is fine... except when I replace the second argument of useEffect from [ url ] to [ url, options ]. 
When 'options' is there, we're entering in the well known infinite loop... however it's logical to have it in this array. What's wrong here?
Thanks

Comment: I'm curious why you're using `useEffect` in `useMyFetch`. Is it that you want to memoize the response by the `url` and `options`? That means you assume the response doesn't change over time, is that really true?

Comment: go the link and show the solution https://repl.it/repls/CumbersomeCruelCopyright

Comment: offtopic: your `useMyFetch` need to include [some cleanup](https://medium.com/hackernoon/avoiding-race-conditions-when-fetching-data-with-react-hooks-220d6fd0f663) in `useEffect` or you get race conditions

Answer (score 1):

Define `{ method: 'GET' }` as a constant object so that the `options` parameter will be always the same, here is an example:

```
const options = { method: 'GET' };
function Example() {
  const res = useMyFetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random", options);
  ...
}
```

Otherwise, `options` will be considered as changed every time the `useMyFetch` is called because `{ method: 'GET' } === { method: 'GET' }` is `false`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The OP mentioned that adding `options` to the array passed as the second parameter to `useEffect` is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

look the URL for testing [show the image](https://repl.it/repls/CumbersomeCruelCopyright)
it should return the setResponse what you want

```
const useMyFetch = (url, options) => 
{
  const [response, setResponse]   = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => 
  {
    console.log("going to fetch ", url);

    fetch(url, options).then(async (response)=> 
    {
      var json = await response.json();
       return setResponse(json.message);
    });

  }, [ url ]); 

  return response;
};



function Example() 
{
  const res = useMyFetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random", { method: 'GET' });

  if (!res) 
  {
    return <div>loading...</div>
  }

  return <img src={res} alt="an image" />;
}


export default Example;
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Titus already mentioned it's because `{ method: 'GET' }` is referentially different each new render. But I believe moving that out the component is not flexible enough in real life. Need to pass token to headers or any other dynamic calculation is rather expected requirement, right?

**Option 1.** We may use `JSON.stringify` to pass parameter object as a string:

```
function useMyFetch(url, options) {
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [url, JSON.stringify(options)])
}
```

**Option 2.** We may use `useRef` to [store previous props](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53446665/2071697) and use custom comparison:

```
function useMyFetch(url, options) {
  const prevOptions = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
   ...
   prevOptions.current = options;
  }, [url, customCompare(options, prevOptions.current)])
}
```

**Option 3.** And finally me may create custom hook that would return referentially same object if all nested properties are equal:

```
function useObject(obj) {
  const prevObj = useRef(obj);
  const isEqual = _.isEqual(prevObj.current, obj);
  useEffect(() => {
    prevObj.current = obj;
  }, [isEqual]);
  return isEqual ? prevObj.current : obj;
}
```

and use it later as

```
function Example() 
{
  const requestOptions = useObject({ method: 'GET' });
  const res = useMyFetch("https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random", requestOptions);

  if (!res) 
  {
    return <div>loading...</div>
  }

  return <img src={res} alt="an image" />;
}
```

**Option 4.** Most straightforward way is to decompose object `options` into primitive values:

```
function useMyFetch(url, options) {
  const {method, headers: {contentType} = {} , ...rest } = options;
  useEffect(() => {
  }, [url, method, contentType, JSON.stringify(rest)]);
}
```

I believe while this method is more verboose than others above, it's slightly faster especially if `rest` typically is empty(no extra headers).

Comment: It's not clear to me what the OP really wants to do, but **if** comparing objects is part of the answer, you'll want to go a bit further than the above. `JSON.stringify({a: 1, b: 2}) !== JSON.stringify({b: 2, a: 1})` per specified behavior. You'd need to do something like `JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(o).sort(([[k1]], [[k2]]) => k1.localeCompare(k2))
    ))` and at that point, you're better off just writing an object comparison function.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sure, you're right. I have described custom comparator usage as well. By the way, while using literal object construction there is no chance for providing keys in different ordering.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your final sentence there.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder having call `useMyFetch(url, {a: 1, b: 2})` there is no chance to get `JSON.stringify(options)` returns different result

Comment: Yes, but you can call `useMyFetch(url, {a: 1, b: 2})` in one place and `useMyFetch(url, {b: 2, a: 1})` in another.