# How to store old array and compare it to the new updated array useRef and useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Currently I am building a **Hanging man** game, where I want to store the old `array length` and compare it to the `new array length`. I know that `useRef` is the stuff I need to get this done. Could someone help me with this.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        
        const checkLetter = (event) => {
            let letter = String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode).toLowerCase();
            if(event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
                setCount(count + 1);
                setGuessed(prev => {
                    const next = [...prev, letter]
                    counter(next);
                    return next;
                });
            } 
        }
 
        document.addEventListener('keydown', checkLetter);

        return () => {
            document.removeEventListener('keydown', checkLetter);
        }
    }, [guessed, count]);

const counter = (letterArray) => {
 let oldArray = letterArray.filter((v, i) => letterArray.indexOf(v) === i);  
  // currently oldArray outputs for instance ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  // if someone clicks on a new letter for instance 'd', the new updated array becomes ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']. And if I want to compare the old array with new updated array for instance like: oldArray !== newUpdatedArray, it returns true. 
    }
```

if current old array is `['a', 'b', 'c']` and you recently clicked on letter **d**, the new updated array becomes `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. And then i want to compare `['a', 'b', 'c'] !== ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`;

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. You want to avoid duplicated elements inside your array?

Comment: no i updated the answer, the oldArray is the current array, and the new one is the one that has recently been updated.

Comment: You want a function that returns if a given letter is already inside an array?

Comment: No i want to compare the old array with the new updated array.

Comment: What exactly this comparison should do?

Comment: if current array is ['a', 'b', 'c'] and you recently clicked on letter 'd', the array becomes ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']. And then i want to compare ['a', 'b', 'c'] !== ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];

Comment: `const compareByLength = (old, new) => old.length === new.length`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare oldValues and newValues on React Hooks useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446020/how-to-compare-oldvalues-and-newvalues-on-react-hooks-useeffect)

Comment: `const compareStringify = (old, new) => JSON.stringify(old) === JSON.stringify(new)`

Comment: React docs, `usePrevious` hook: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state

Answer (score 0):

Arrays will be compared by refs, so even `[] === []` will always return false. You probably need to compare by values. If you always adds letters to the end of array, you probably can check by just:

```js
const compare = (array1, array2) => {
  if (array1.length !== array2.length) {
    return false;
  }

  return array1.every(
    (item, index) => item === array2[index]
  );
}
```

If you want compare only values and you don't care about order:

```js
const isIn = (array1, array2) => {
  return array1.every(
    return array2.includes(item);
  );
}

const compare = (array1, array2) => isIn(array1, array2) || isIn(array2, array1);
```

You can also use `lodash.difference()` for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply compare arrays length

```
const compareArr = (oldArr, newArr) => oldArr.length === newArr.length
```

It will return true if array has same length as before and false if length has changed

Hope it helps