# api call with every key stroke

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I tried to create this react website where I can search for a place. I'm having a problem cause whenever I enter a new letter in the search box, the api is called which is making the website very slow. I don't want it to call the api with every keystroke. I think this is because of the second useEffect but if I remove that useEffect then no results are displayed in the search results. How can I tackle this problem. in class component I think we can do it with componentDidUpdate but here I used useEffect but not getting the desired result.

Here's the code

App.js

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getItems();

    if (finalSearch) {
      filterData();
    } else {
      handleRequest();
    }
  }, [search, finalSearch]);
```

Comment: You've described the problem, but you haven't explained what it is you're trying to do to solve it. How often _do_ you want to call the API?

Comment: just once. then the results are saved in the data right. so I want to make the search from there and not make api call with every key stroke cause it's making it slow

Comment: In addition to providing a link to the CodeSandBox, please post code here that is relevant to your question.

Comment: ok sir, I will do that now

Comment: Sounds like you would want to debounce the API call until the user stops tying.

Comment: yeah I think that can work. How can I implement it here? @JMadelaine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you call the api at the beginning and then once the search component has values, you filter the data.

If you want to stop fetching the API on each keystroke, just remove the else clause in your useEffect.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    getResults();

    if (finalSearch) {
      filterData();
    }
  }, [search, finalSearch]);
```

Comment: wow, that worked. what if I want to make it a progressive web app? how to cache the data? you got any ideas