# React - api data is being successfully passed to component(per inspector) but not being rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, rendering

My api data is being successfully passed from my api call into the table component but is not being rendered.

If after searching for a playlist I go in and make an edit to the table.js file the data will render correctly.
App.js...

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [playlists, setPlaylists] = useState([])
  const [searchString, setSearchString] = useState() //use instead of onsubmit 
  const isFirstRef = useRef(true);
  
  const search = (value) => {
    setSearchString(value)
  }

  useEffect(
    () => {
      if (isFirstRef.current) {
      isFirstRef.current = false;
      return;
      }
      let spotlist = Spotify.playlistsearch(searchString)
      let tablelist = []
      spotlist.then(val =>{
        val.forEach(element =>{
          tablelist.push(
            { 
              name: element.description,
              track_count: element.tracks.total,
            })
        } 
      )})
      setPlaylists(tablelist)
      }, [searchString] );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Searchform search={search}/>
      <Table playlists={playlists}/>
    </div>
  )
};
```

The playlists prop is being shown as present under the PlayListTable component inspector but is not rendering. I am able to get the data to render IF I edit the file after seeing the data present in the component inspector.
Table.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Icon, Label, Menu, Table } from 'semantic-ui-react'

const PlayListTable = ({ playlists }) => {
  return(
    <Table celled>
      <Table.Header>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Playlist</Table.HeaderCell>
          <Table.HeaderCell>Track Count</Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Header>
      <Table.Body>
       {playlists.map( (playlist) => {
          return (
              <Table.Row>
                <Table.Cell>
                  {playlist.name}
                </Table.Cell>
                <Table.Cell>
                  {playlist.track_count}
                </Table.Cell>
              </Table.Row>
              )
            }
          )
        }
      </Table.Body>
      <Table.Footer>
        <Table.Row>
          <Table.HeaderCell colSpan='3'>
            <Menu floated='right' pagination>
              <Menu.Item as='a' icon>
                <Icon name='chevron left' />
              </Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item as='a'>1</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item as='a'>2</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item as='a'>3</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item as='a'>4</Menu.Item>
              <Menu.Item as='a' icon>
                <Icon name='chevron right' />
              </Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
          </Table.HeaderCell>
        </Table.Row>
      </Table.Footer>
    </Table>
  )
}

export default PlayListTable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

You may be receiving correct data but you don't update your state at the correct time. `spotlist` returns a Promise that you are chaining from, but the `setPlaylists(tablelist)` call is enqueued *before* the `then` block of the promise chain is processed. The `useEffect` callback is 100% synchronous code.

```
let spotlist = Spotify.playlistsearch(searchString);
let tablelist = [];
spotlist.then(val => { // <-- (1) then callback is placed in the event queue
  val.forEach(element => { // <-- (3) callback is processed, tablelist updated
    tablelist.push({ 
      name: element.description,
      track_count: element.tracks.total,
    });
  } 
)});
setPlaylists(tablelist); // <-- (2) state update enqueued, tablelist = []
```

## Solution - Place state update in Promise chain

You can `forEach` into a temp array, but mapping the response data to state values is the more "React" way of handling it. It is also more succinct.

```
Spotify.playlistsearch(searchString)
  .then(val => {
    setPlaylists(val.map(element => ({
      name: element.description,
      track_count: element.tracks.total,
    })));
  } 
)});
```

Answer (score 0):

The first note I’d have is that your use effect will not trigger unless something changes with searchString since it’s in the dependency array. Additionally, I believe that your first ref condition prevents the first render from setting up, so it could be causing issues.

It may be better to look into something like a previous check, I’ve used the solution for a common hook from here before: [How to compare oldValues and newValues on React Hooks useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446020/how-to-compare-oldvalues-and-newvalues-on-react-hooks-useeffect)

When you say the playlist prop is showing up, are there actual values?

On other edit make sure the return value from map has proper keys: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html