# ReactJS: How to detect value changed into another componet and compare with previous?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

I am doing a simple exercise to clear my hook concept.

In my current scenario, I need to call the `API` only if i click on the `Call API` button and that time the page number should be the current value of `Click Me` button value.

But currently, on every `Click Me` button click the API is called.

I have tried with this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446020/how-to-compare-oldvalues-and-newvalues-on-react-hooks-useeffect), but can not get the result.

```
const usePrevious = (value) => {
  const ref = useRef();
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  });
  console.log(ref.current);
  return ref.current;
};

export default function GetAPIData(props) {
  const [chars, setChars] = useState([]);
  const prevCount = usePrevious(props.id);
  console.log(
    "Previous value is: " + prevCount,
    "Current value is: " + props.id
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/?page=${props.id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setChars(res.data.results);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        alert(err.message);
      });
  }, [prevCount, props.id]);

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <h3>
        <span>Achtung,</span> ein Trend geht um
      </h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the working [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/twilight-water-4uxm0?file=/src/components/GetAPIData.js) URL for reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are updating the state every time when you click on the button by that the page was re-render and useEffect() is calling the API.
Try to create a new state which only changes when you click on the Call API. By that, your component does not re-render on the change of count.
Might it help You