# How to compare oldValues and newValues on React Hooks useEffect? Multiple re-renders

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

The kinda the same problem as described here
[How to compare oldValues and newValues on React Hooks useEffect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53446020/how-to-compare-oldvalues-and-newvalues-on-react-hooks-useeffect)

But in my case, `usePrevious` hook does not help.

Imagine the form with several inputs, selects, and so on. You may want to look at https://app.uniswap.org/#/swap to make a similar visualization. There are several actions and data updates that will be happened on almost any change, which will lead to several re-renders, at least 4. For example.

I have 2 inputs, each represents a token. Base(first one) and Quote(second one).

This is a state for Base

```
const [base, setBase] = useState({
    balance: undefined,
    price: undefined,
    value: initState?.base?.value,
    token: initState?.base?.token,
    tokenId: initState?.base?.tokenId,
});
```

and for Quote

```
const [quote, setQuote] = useState({
    balance: undefined,
    price: undefined,
    value: initState?.quote?.value,
    token: initState?.quote?.token,
    tokenId: initState?.quote?.tokenId,
});
```

They gonna form a pair, like **BTC/USD** for example.

By changing `token` (instead of **BTC** I will choose **ETH**) in the select menu I will trigger several actions: fetching wallet balance, fetching price, and there are gonna be a few more rerenders with input view update and modal window close. So at least 4 of them are happening right now. I want to be able to compare `base.token` and `basePrv` with
`const basePrv = usePrevious(base?.token);` but on the second re-render `base.token` and `basePrv` gonna have the same token property already and it is an issue.

I also have the swap functionality between the inputs where I should change base with quote and quote with base like that

```
setBase(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    base: quote
}));

setQuote(prevState => ({
    ...prevState,
    quote: base
}));
```

In that case, there are no additional requests that should be triggered.

Right now I have `useEffect` with `token` dependency on it. But it will be fired each time when the token gonna be changed which will lead to additional asynchronous calls and 'tail' of requests if you gonna click fast. That's why I need to compare the `token` property that was before the change to understand should I make additional calls and requests because of the formation of new pair (**BTC/USD** becomes **ETH/USD**) or I should ignore that because it was just a "swap" (**BTC/USD** becomes **USD/BTC**) and there is no need to make additional calls and fetches. I just had to, well, swap them, not more.

So in my story, `usePrevious` hook will return the previous token property only once, and at the second and third time, it would be overwritten by multiple re-renders(other properties would be fetched) to the new one. So at the time when `useEffect` gonna be triggered, I would have no chance to compare the previous token property and the current one, because they will show the same.

I have several thoughts on how to solve it, but I am not sure is it right or wrong, because it seemed to me that the decisions look more imperative than declarative.

1. I can leave everything as it is (requests would be triggered always on any change no matter what it was. Was it a swap or user changed a pair). I can disable the swap button until all of the requests would be finished. It would solve the problem with requests 'tail'. But it is a kinda hotfix, that gonna be work, but I do not like it, because it would lead to additional unnecessary requests and it would be slow and bad for UX.
2. I can use a state to keep the previous pair on it right before the update by `setBase` or `setQuote` happens. It will allow me to use useEffect and compare previous pair to the current one to understand did the pair was changed, or just swapped and take the decision should I make fetches and calls or not.
3. I can get rid of `useEffect` with `base.token` and `quote.token` dependencies and handle everything inside of `onClick` handler. Because of that, the swap functionality would not trigger `useEffect`, and calls and fetches would be fired only if the user gonna click and choose something different. But as I said this option seemed a little bit odd to me.
4. I tried to use closure here, to "remember" the previous state of tokens, but it is kinda similar to use the current component state. Also, you have to initialize closure outside of the functional component body, and I do not see a possibility to transfer the init state into it that way, so the code becomes more spaghettified.

So any other ideas guys? I definitely missing something. Maybe that much of re-renders is an antipattern but I am not sure how to avoid that.

Comment: Why don't you create a prevBase state and update it whenever you can setBase ?

Comment: This is a decision I described in the 2-nd case. Yes, it is possible, but I took the 3-rd option because in that way I do not need to add additional conditions or states or patches on tokens swap. While by using `useEffect` it should use some conditions to check and determine should I make calls or not. So I just left everything on click handlers. I am just not sure if it is a good practice or not.

Comment: I'm making an answer since I can't give code examples in comment. Let me know if it provides a solution.
.
.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There could be multiple solutions to your problem. I would suggest to pick one which is easier to understand.

### 1. Modify the `usePrevious` hook

You can modify the `usePrevious` hook to survive multiple renders.

**Tip:** use `JSON.stringify` to compare if you think the value will be a complex object and might change the reference even for same real value.

```js
function usePrevious(value) {
  const prevRef = useRef();
  const curRef = useRef();

  if (value !== curRef.current){
  // or, use
  // if ( JSON.stringify(value) !== JSON.stringify(curRef.current)){
    prevRef.current = curRef.current;
    curRef.current = value;
  }
  
  return prevRef.current;
}
```

### 2. Sort `useEffect` dependency array

Since you're using tokens(strings) as dependency array of `useEffect`, and you don't mind their order (swap shouldn't change anything), sort the dependency array like

```js
useEffect(
  () => {
    // do some effect
  },
  [base.token, quote.token].sort()
)
```

### 3. Store the currently fetched tokens.

While storing the API response data, also store the tokens(part of request) associated with that data. Now, you'll have 2 sets of tokens.

1. currently selected tokens
2. currently fetched tokens

You can chose to fetch only when the currently fetched tokens don't fulfil your needs. You can also extend this and store previous API request/responses and pick the result from them if possible.

### Verdict

Out of all these, 3rd seems a nice & more standardised approach to me, but an overkill for your need (unless you want to cache previous results).

I would have gone with 2nd because of simplicity and minimalism. However, It still depends on what you find easier at the end.

Comment: Thank you! The second seemed to be a good one. Actually, they are not strings, but objects, but it can be possible, to have their symbols as dependencies. I am just confused about having so many things inside of the click handler of the picked token item. But in the end, a better solution is that one, which can be readed and modified easily without accidental surprising results and issues.

I am craving about having someones review, but the project is NDA, so it is not possible to share.