# Preventing the React Router's current path from changing whenever the confirmation is false

Tags: reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I'm having trouble in preventing the path from redirecting whenever I click the browser's back button then click the "Cancel" button in the confirmation box.

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', this.quit);
}

quit = () => {
    if(confirm('Quit?')) {
        location.assign('/'); // Refreshes the browser then redirects to the homepage
        history.pushState(null, null, null); // Clears the previous history
    } else {
        // What to do if the user clicks "Cancel"?
    }
}
```

I tried `return false` but it's still redirecting the app to the homepage (but without refreshing the page). I've tried other solutions like `location.pathname = '/currentPathname'` and `location.replace('/currentPathname')`, but since these reload the browser, it displays `Cannot get /currentPathname` because React Router doesn't need to reload. The `<Prompt />` component didn't solve the problem as well because it doesn't have a function prop where I can execute the code above.

Comment: Try changing the event listener to `beforeunload` instead of `popstate`

Comment: Worse. No confirmation and refreshing of page happened

Comment: Try the suggestions on this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32841757/detecting-user-leaving-page-with-react-router/37937895

Comment: Your best bet to accomplishing your initial goal is to use the `<Prompt />` to prevent unwanted navigation. I'm not sure why you need to execute that specific bit of code, as the browser normally takes care of that. 

I also created a CodeSandbox with my attempt at it: https://codesandbox.io/s/m3o0wv1w29

Comment: Problem solved! `<Prompt />` with the help of `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` fixed the issue. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to accomplishing your initial goal is to use the  to prevent unwanted navigation. You may also benefit from using both `componentDidMount` and `componentWillUnmount` like so:

```
componentDidUpdate = () => {
    //Prompt Browser Refresh / Close
    if ("Your Condition" || true) {
      window.onbeforeunload = () => true;
    } else {
      window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
    }
};

componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({ shouldPrompt: true });
    this.props.history.listen((location, action) => {
      console.log(location);
      if (action === "POP") {
      }
    });
}

...

render() {
    return (
        <Prompt
          when={shouldPrompt}
          message="You have unsaved changes, are you sure you want to leave?"
        >
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/" component={Page1} exact />
            <Route path="/page2" component={Page2} exact />
          </Switch>
        </Prompt>
    )
}
```

Comment: I've seen this tip before. It's helpful though

Comment: @jstarnate I wrote it as an answer which you could use to mark the question as solved with