How to Warn Users Before Changing Tabs or Minimizing Window During an Online Quiz?
I am conducting an online quiz,
Here is what I want to achieve:
Detect when a user tries to switch tabs or windows.
Detect when a user tries to minimize the window.
Display a warning message before the user changes the tab or minimizes the window.
Automatically submit the test if the user continues with the action after the warning.
document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function() {
if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden') {
alert('Warning: You are about to leave the quiz. If you continue, your test will be submitted.');
// Logic to submit the test
}
});
window.addEventListener('blur', function() {
alert('Warning: You are about to switch tabs. If you continue, your test will be submitted.');
// Logic to submit the test
});
Problems with my approach:
The warning message appears after the user has already switched tabs or minimized the window.
I need a way to capture these actions before they happen.
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

A 100% check wont be possible since the system can always shut down the browser itself. For closing a window you can go with beforeunload events (https://vercel.com/guides/leave-page-confirmation-dialog-before-unload-nextjs-react (tough next example the same logic applies))  for a more react native version take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49163569/19801189

This works when the user tries to reload or close the tab but i want the warning to be displayed when the user tries to change tab.

A workaround could be to build an invisible (not hidden but transparent) overlay over the whole page. Then a mouse move, enter & exit event listener that sets e.g. a boolean value + a timer that checks the value. If the value isn't set the user isn't "on the page"

You can't catch them "attempting to leave" because they still haven't left yet! :)
I would display a message on the screen during the quiz along the lines of...
"Please note that abandoning this tab during a quiz may cause the loss of your progress"
And then...
document.onvisibilitychange=()=>{

 if (document.visibilityState === 'hidden'){

  // OMG the user has left... let's blow away the page!

   document.body.innerHTML= 'Sorry, you abandoned the page and your quiz has been lost!';

 }

};

Kinda nasty but you did warn! :)
And if you want something really funny load a BSOD image on the background!
https://news-cdn.softpedia.com/images/news2/microsoft-confirms-windows-10-dpc-watchdog-violation-bsod-promises-fix-493754-2.jpg
